# I need remove unnecessary json objects form my result json file using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json

I have result json file with 10000 of lines. inside the one array object  there are some unnecessary json object i need remove. I have tried so many ways but it's didn't work for me. herewith the piece line of json file

```
[
  {
    "product_id": "easybridge",
    "errors": []
  },
  {
    "product_id": "learningstudio",
    "errors": []
  },
  {
    "product_id": "pearsontestprep",
    "errors": []
  },
  {
    "product_id": "productization",
    "errors": []
  },
  {
    "product_id": "equella",
    "errors": [
      {
        "property": "instance.test_ids[1]",
        "message": "requires property \"maintenance\"",
        "schema": {
          "$id": "#/properties/test_ids/items",
          ],
          "properties": {
            "trend": {
              "$id": "#/properties/test_ids/items/properties/trend",
              "examples": [
                true
              ]
            },
            "display": {
              "$id": "#/properties/test_ids/items/properties/display",
              "type": "boolean",
              "examples": [
                true
              ]
            },
            "test_id": {
              "$id": "#/properties/test_ids/items/properties/test_id",
              "type": "string",
            },
            "test_name": {
              "$id": "#/properties/test_ids/items/properties/test_name",
              "type": "string",
            },
            "maintenance": {
              "$id": "#/properties/test_ids/items/properties/maintenance",
              "type": "boolean",
              ]
            },
        "instance": {
          "trend": false,
          "display": false,
          "test_id": "8597ae3c-e2a9-45c7-b279-bde1710681be",
          "test_name": "Equella Pearsonresearch Ping Test",
          "nrAlertStatus": "enabled",
          "test_locations": [
            {

              "alert_state": false,
              "location_name": "AWS_US_WEST_2",
              "location_label": "Portland, OR, USA",
              "included_to_health": false
            }
          ],
          "included_to_health": false,
          "critical_alert_threshold": 60
        },
        "name": "required",
        "argument": "maintenance",
        "stack": "instance.test_ids[1] requires property \"maintenance\""

  {
    "product_id": "easybridge",
    "errors": []
  },
```

I just need only

```
{
    "product_id": "equella",
    "errors": [
      {
        "property": "instance.test_ids[1]",
        "message": "requires property \"maintenance\"",
      }
 },
```

if the errors json array is not empty. i don't need even this json how can i remove "schema" json object and other unnecessary json object and arrays specially "schema" json object using java script or java. please help

Comment: Could you provide one of your solutions so that we have something to build on?

Comment: Hey, It looks like your JSON example is not valid. Can you update your question with correct JSON example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array, look at each object, and create a new array by copying over the data you need.

For instance, I'm taking it you don't care about an object if its array of errors is empty, and that you don't care about the `schema` ever:

```
let newJSON = [];

//Assume the json variable is the parsed JSON file you posted.
for (let element of json) {

    //Must have at least one error
    if (element.errors.length > 0) {

        //Create a new object
        let newObj = {
            "product_id" : element.product_id,
            "errors" : []
        };

        //Add each errror

        for (let error of element.errors) {

            //Only copy across what we need
            newObj.errors.push({
                "property" : error.property,
                "message" : error.message
            });
        }

        //Add object to our new array of JSON
        newJSON.push(newObj);
    }
}

//newJSON is your processed JSON output
```

Comment: This code also perfectly work for me. thanks @Toastrackenigma. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution can be:

```js
const records = [{
  "product_id": "learningstudio",
  "errors": []
},
{
  "product_id": "pearsontestprep",
  "errors": []
},
{
  "product_id": "equella",
  "errors": [{
    "property": "instance.test_ids[1]",
    "message": "requires property \"maintenance\"",
    "schema": {
      "$id": "#/properties/test_ids/items",
     }
  }]
}];

const filteredRecords = records.map((record) => {
  record.errors = record.errors.map((error) => {
    return {property: error. property, message: error.message};
  });
  return record;  
});

console.log(filteredRecords);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**destructuring assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to capture only desired properties

```js
let json = [{"product_id": "equella", "errors": [{"property": "instance.test_ids[1]","message": "requires property \"maintenance\"",'xyz': 'not needed','useless': 'not needed',},{'xyz': 'not needed',}]},]
 
let op = json.map(({product_id,errors}) =>{ 
 let { property, message } = errors[0]
 return { product_id, errors: {property,message}}
})
 
 console.log(op)
```